# Store registered and non registered users payment

Tags: php, mysql

I have developed a **PHP** and **MySQL** website which has a registration form for users and a payment for running races.

The problem is some people, want to pay without registration despite they have to type the runner info on every race payment.

My actual MySQL Schema is

- USERS (**id**, username, password, email)
- USER_PROFILES (**user_id**, name, surname, gender, birthdate, etc...)
- EVENTS (**id**, name_desc, date)
- REGISTRATIONS (**id**, **user_id**, **event_id**, signup_date, bank_order, bank_result)

At the beginning it was very easy to register some runner, store all the info, and go to EPOS, receive the order and result of bank, and I have an SQL to retrieve all registered runners who paid the event running race.

Now I am blocked in the idea, how to do if an user, doesn't want to register, or don't have an email account.

My idea is the possibility of developing an simple form to fill a form runner data, and go to pay, or type another, and then pay all ammount of all runners instead each one in their account.

Due to my website schema, I don't know how to improve my actual site with this other feature.

I hope I have explained everything perfect. Sorry about my bad English.

Thanks colleagues.

Ricardo. Yet Another PHP Developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider adding the concept of a "guest user".

Basically, you treat "guest" checkouts the same as your regular checkouts, but you would add a new `type` column to your USERS table. Your new schema might look like this: `USERS (id, type, username, password, email)`
Choose an identifier for the `type` column like 'R' (for "Registered") and 'G' (for "Guest") and you'll be able to easily discern which kind of user you've got.

You'll have to update your site's code to disallow logins for guest users and not require those accounts to have a password or username, but all the other tables should be able to use the provided `user_id` of the guest user.

Also make sure your database schema doesn't have a Unique index on the Users.email column, as that'll prevent a user from going through the guest checkout multiple times.

Comment: I disagree. I think registration should be simple but compulsory.

Comment: Thank you very much Strawberry for your very good Idea.

My only problem now is how to do if an user register as guest in a race, and in a second one, or third. Do I retrieve the old data? or do I add a "new user" in the table as new ID user?

My question is, because the "userdata" is the Spanish ID, unique not null.

Comment: Thank you very much Strawberry. I shall develop the "(G)uest" solution. I have only a last issue because the web, allows login by username (ID) or email, and I have to be careful with possible duplicates. Thank you, Thank you, Thank you :)